# matplotlib mathtext does not work

Tags: math, matplotlib

I'm doing a hist plot and I want some numbers shown in the plot, so I put in a text box using mathtext for the text, but I doesn't work and I can't see why.

```
a = [2086., 360.5, 1000.]

b = [977., 37., 498.]

c = [4512., 690., 378.]


textstr = r'$\per50=%.2f$\n$\per16=%.2f$\n$\per84=%.2f$'%(a[0],b[0],c[0])

    # these are matplotlib.patch.Patch properties
    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.75)

    # place a text box in upper left in axes coords
    ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
            verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
```

At the end of my figure I'm getting this error:

```
matplotlib.pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected end of math '$'
$\per50=2086.00$\n$\per16=977.00$\n$\per84=4512.00$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: what is `\per` supposed to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because the command `$\per$` does not exist. Is that a latex command you defined? If you set the matplotlib parameter `text.usetex=True`, it is possible to set a latex preamble and define commands there, e.g.:

```
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble='something')
```

But I don't think this can be used to define new commands (and the use of preamble is discouraged). So your best bet is to write explicitly in matplotlib whatever `\per` stands for.

Comment: Thank you! I have done it like this now: textstr = 'per50 = '+str(a[0])+'\nper16 = '+str(b[0])+'\nper84 = '+str(c[0]), which might not be the "perfect" way, but it works. But at least I now know, what the error was. Thanx

Comment: Glad it helped. By the way, I've seen in your profile that you never accepted an answer. In this website this is a way of bestowing recognition, rewarding people for answering, and also to guide people that arrive here with the same question. So you should consider accepting more answers.